# Form is not in correct position in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

http://www.campbellcustomcoatings.com/index2.php

At this site, I'm using css3's box shadow and rgba for the content background. To make it play nice with IE7, i'm using 3 images. The Form element is cleared underneath the main content area and it's supposed to be to the right of it.

Any body know why?

Comment: index2.php b/c this is a live site that i'm just doing some updating and i used index2 as a copy. backgroundBottom.png should be referenced in the ie.css stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I didn't touch your **main2.css**.  That still uses `float:right` to layout the form for FF/Chrome/Safari.  My solution uses `position:absolute` to layout the form in **ie.css**.

I think this is the simplest/quickest way to fix your web page for **IE7+**.

Personally, I would go back and refactor **main2.css** for more code consistency, you would probably end up with less code in **ie.css** that way (which is what I typically strive for).

I used *absolute positioning*, because I knew it would work.  You could probably use *relative positioning* too.  It would be tricky to use *float positioning*.  I find using *relative/absolute* is easier to achieve cross-browser compatibility in some situations, but I could be wrong.  I'm sure there are other ways to skin this cat too, maybe even better ones.

If you want any other tips or suggestions, or if the steps below don't 100% work for you, let me know.  Your site looks awesome btw.

Starting with your latest version of **index2.php, main2.css, and ie.css**:

**In index2.php**

move `<div id="form">` inside of:

`div#container`

**In ie.css**

get rid of:

`#form { float:right; }`

get rid of:

`#container #bottom { clear: left; }`

add:

`#container #content { float:none; }`

change:

`#container #bottom { margin: 0; }`

to:

`#container #bottom { margin: 0 0 0 35px; }`

add :

`#container { position:relative; } /* this sets the parent element for the next line */`

finally add:

`#form { position:absolute; right:0; top:-15px; }`

As you know, you still need to add your graphics back into the `div#form`, and also put the top and bottom rounded graphics on the `div#form`.  If you have any problems and need help with that let me know.  Hopefully the techniques about will help you finish it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you guys are not seeing it. I'm seeing it as a 20 px strip right above the "free consultation" sticker. Are you guys viewing this in ie7?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand why this is happening, try putting a brightly colored margin on the div with id="container".

You will see that its width is as specified in the CSS, but in IE 8 and Firefox its height is zero.  This is because it contains only empty divs and a floating div, which is rendered outside the normal flow of the page.

However, in IE 7 "container" has a height which includes the height of the floating div with id="content".  This causes it to push the div with id="form" down below it.

If you want "form" to show up in the space which (in IE 7) is occupied by "container", you could try making "form" a child of "container".

Comment: Also, if you want "container" to have that height in all browsers (for consistency's sake) you could add `<div>&nbsp;</div>` as the last child of container, and give that div `clear:both`

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not [validating](http://validator.w3.org). Try first to fix that, it might not fix the problem, but at least you'll have a good basis to work from.

Having valid HTML/CSS is fundamental before trying to fix rendering issues and quirks, as not all browsers treat invalid markup the same way.

Answer (score 0):

On my IE7 everything is showing OK,if you have solved the problem you could post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The div#form is outside you div#container.

Try this :

- Put div#form inside container after div#content
- Set div#form float:right; instead of left
- Adjust div#content and div#form width/padding/margins so they can both fit in div#container's width.

Comment: 1st bullet, that's how he used to have it; 2nd bullet, he has the div#form float:right in ie.css